# EventEmitter.once() inside a setInterval for read data at requested time intervals

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, eventemitter

I have this code:

```
device.on('found', success => {
  success.once('updated', data => {
    console.log('Got data ' + data);
  });
});
```

The problem is that 'device' is a bluetooth device that sends data every second.
So every time i found a device I start listening for updates and every update I have my data.

I want that my device continues to share data every seconds but, how I can read one 'update' every 10 minutes (for example)?

If I put succes.on(), the code inside will be called every second... If I put succes.once(), the code is called only once, I tried to put this function inside a setInterval but it doesn't work...

My goal is to read data posted from an event emitters whet I want, and not when he post, It is correct that it continues posting but I want read at some specific time intervals...

Some helps? 
Thank you!